# Releasing Mat images with openCV(.release() and =Mat() doesn't work)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have tried to release a Mat image from my program, however, no matter how I tried it, the same image (result) still appear when I click on the "process button" to process another image (from loading or snapping an image). The old results will always be displayed.

I have to close the whole program, open the next image I want to process and click the "process button" to get the actual result. However, this is not ideal, as I want my program to immediately process the image I load or snap and not having to close the whole program(or rather stop run and click run again)

Most of the results I searched from google suggested these methods:

```
imagep.release(); //where imagep is the image after going through processing
imagep=Mat();
```

UPDATE:
My code is goes something along this line. In my program.h file, the image and image p and declared like this:

```
class program : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    program(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~program();
    cv::Mat image, imagep; //original image and image processed
```

The coding for the button in the .cpp file goes something like this:

```
imagep = image.clone();      //also tried: imagep=image, and imagep=image+0 already.
.
.
.
processing/segmenting steps
.
.
cv::imshow("new image", imagep);
cvWaitKey(10);
imagep=Mat();     //also tried cvDestroyWindow("new image"), //imagep.release();
```

The setting of the picture of imagep(where I changed the values of the pixels based on results from the image processing. ) is created via:

```
for (int i=0; i< imagep.rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<imagep.cols; ++j)
    {
        //imagep.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)= v_char[i]; Note that this is commented. This method doesn't work, hence the below method. But it doesn't work too.
            Vec3b temp=v_char[i];
        imagep.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0]=temp[0];
        imagep.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1]=temp[1];
        imagep.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2]=temp[2];



    }
}
```

However, these methods doesn't work. Any suggestions of how I can release the Mat image?

Comment: So the problem is that you `imagep` is not destructing properly?

Comment: Yes. Do you have any idea what might be the cause?

Comment: Is the problem that you never destroy the window? Or with the actual `imagep` variable not being destructed?

Comment: imagep variable is not being destructed. The interaction is done through a GUI too, so the usual method to destroy the window is a waitkey, however, I do not want the user to touch the keyboard at all, all he/she have is a mouse.

Comment: See http://answers.opencv.org/question/14285/how-to-free-memory-through-cvmat/ It will only be released if it owns the memory

Comment: Yes, I did google and came across that post. However, imagep is not from old structures or created from pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

waitKey(-1) wait for a keyboard input while waitKey(10) uses 10 ms to update UI and then passes to control further on; It seems to that your problem is not release but proper update.

Normally one don’t need to release Mat (though I saw some release() calls in Java), just reassign it. Your problem may also be related to smart pointers that got killed when the number of references goes to zero but it is hard to say without seeing your code.

There are some tricky things happening when creating, assigning, and declaring Mats. Also, note for example that Mat m = n, copies the reference only but Mat m = n + 0, copies the whole object.

Comment: thanks for your answer, yup, I have too tried waitKey() with different timings, but to no avail. The initial plan was to reassign the Mat as you have said, like in the case of image, when a new image is snapped, the Mat is reassigned with no problem, but when it comes to imagep, the Mat is unable to be reassigned. That was why I was trying to release the image. Already tried your method too of Mat m=n and Mat m=n+0 but it didn't work:/

Comment: I add in a little of my code, do hope you are able to tell what the problem is from that little bit of code of mine. Upvoted your answer anyway, and once again, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I looked at your code and so far did not find any error. What is the problem exactly? I don't quite understand how not releasing creates a problem. You said it did not work. Does it means you cannot see how image changes? Can you please just tell me what you need/expect and what actually happens?

Comment: I realised why the new image cannot be assigned or released. Cuz the vector v_char[i] declaration somehow disappear :/ Hence, every time, the button is clicked, as there is not declaration, the processing just add on to the image. A hindsight on my part:( So difficult to debug such stuff when compiling shows now error. However, since you are the only one who replied, an accepted answer on top of the upvote I gave you. Thanks(:

Comment: Thanks and no problem; you did not mention anything about a mystique button. If you had shown the whole code of yours including compiler errors we would have resolved this issue much faster. Do you write an Android app?

Comment: I did metion about the button. Haha. In regards to android apps, yes. But for this coding, no. (: I am afraid I can't show the whole code as this is a program to test out an algorithm tat my prof and I created. So I cant show the whole thing. Only the non sensitive parts.